# Use Python to scrape information with exactly same class information

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape information from this website https://www.gurufocus.com/insider/summary

There are two price columns with different price values, but their class and elements are totally the same. Here's the class information:

```
<td data-v-575fbbfb="" class="right-align number-field" data-column="Price" row-idx="0">
<span style="color: ">$2.12</span></td>
```

This is part of my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd 
price = []
for pr in soup.find_all('td',{'class': 'right-align number-field','data-column': 'Price'}):
    price.append(pr.text)
```

Does anyone know how to distinguish these two prices and scrape them into two arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()` builtin function for the task.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.gurufocus.com/insider/summary'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

tds = soup.select('td[data-column="Price"]')

price_column_1, price_column_2 = [], []
for td_col1, td_col2 in zip(tds[::2], tds[1::2]):
    price_column_1.append(td_col1.text)
    price_column_2.append(td_col2.text)

# print to screen
for p1, p2 in zip(price_column_1, price_column_2):
    print('{:<10}{}'.format(p1, p2))
```

Prints:

```
$2.05     $2.12
$15.42    $14.79
$0.02     $0.02
$0.64     $0.63
$73.13    $76.89
$298.75   $308.05
$512.74   $517.77
$341.27   $357
$300.99   $311.13
$38.34    $39.02
$20.79    $21.72
$5.65     $5.37
$14.30    $14.43
$37.93    $36.24
$174.90   $177.79
$79.58    $83.49
$79.58    $83.49
$63.91    $66.56
$25.31    $25.90
$93.04    $95.37
$67.73    $72.59
$67.73    $71.59
$67.71    $71.55
$11.31    $10.93
$58.67    $60.62
$22.64    $25.21
$3.98     $4.01
$6.47     $6.25
$9.08     $8.84
$23.69    $23.79
$174.23   $178.10
$100.07   $99.75
$11.89    $12.01
$0.83     $0.83
$41.15    $25
$41.15    $25
$41.15    $25
$7.23     $4.73
$23.04    $21.27
$37.97    $35.57
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) to get the table directly and play with the column names :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.gurufocus.com/insider/summary")

data = pd.read_html(r.text, attrs = {'class': 'data-table'})[0]

data.columns = [
    'Ticker', 'Links', 'Company', 'Price1', 'Insider Name', 'Insider Position', 
    'Date', 'Buy/Sell', 'Insider Trading Shares', 'Shares Change', 'Price2', 
    'Cost(000)', 'Final Share', 'Price Change Since Insider Trade (%)', 
    'Dividend Yield %', 'PE Ratio', 'Market Cap ($M)', 'None'
]

print(data[["Price1","Price2"]])
```

Output:

```
     Price1   Price2
0     $2.05    $2.12
1    $15.42   $14.79
2     $0.02    $0.02
3     $0.64    $0.63
4    $73.13   $76.89
5   $298.75  $308.05
6   $512.74  $517.77
7   $341.27     $357
8   $300.99  $311.13
9    $38.34   $39.02
10   $20.79   $21.72
11    $5.65    $5.37
12   $14.30   $14.43
13   $37.93   $36.24
14  $174.90  $177.79
15   $79.58   $83.49
16   $79.58   $83.49
17   $63.91   $66.56
18   $25.31   $25.90
19   $93.04   $95.37
20   $67.73   $72.59
21   $67.73   $71.59
22   $67.71   $71.55
23   $11.31   $10.93
24   $58.67   $60.62
25   $22.64   $25.21
26    $3.98    $4.01
27    $6.47    $6.25
28    $9.08    $8.84
29   $23.69   $23.79
30  $174.23  $178.10
31  $100.07   $99.75
32   $11.89   $12.01
33    $0.83    $0.83
34   $41.15      $25
35   $41.15      $25
36   $41.15      $25
37    $7.23    $4.73
38   $23.04   $21.27
39   $37.97   $35.57
```

Comment: This is really cool!!! Thank you so much! Do you know how to get the data for multiple pages? I'm very new to web scraping and still trying to figure things out.

Comment: @KristineLian hmm, the pagination is not as straightforward as it looks. When you click on the page, there is an API call triggered. But this API call has an authentication header which is a JWT token. The jwt seems to comes from the JS itself (json) but it also needs a "signature" header (which is itself a JWT).The JWT is constructed in JS, and there is a secret that is used to sign the payload. But, I don't know where is this secret or from where it goes (it is needed to reproduce the auth token). I think, you would be better looking at something like selenium to spare you the trouble.